# Unable to install XDebug extension for PHP 8. Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: apache2, php, xdebug

I entered the output of phpinfo() func on xDebug wizard webpage and then followed all the steps as described in output. Everything looked fine. No errors. The only concern about suggested actions is that it tells - "Make sure that - zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so is below the line for OPcache." But my php.ini file only contain a string : ;zend_extension=opcache. And this string is commented out. All strings that mention OPcache in my php.ini are commented out as well with semicolon marks.
I don't know how to describe my problem more clearly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to answer, I know! But in case you’ve landed here …

`sudo apt install php8.0-xdebug` will put the `zend_extension` location for you in `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` or something similar depending on whether you’re using Apache FPM or whatever.

But take a look at whichever `/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` files exists in `/etc/php/8.0/`

Then you can edit that file and restart Apache, FPM as appropriate.

It’ll be Xdebug 3, so be sure to read the [Updrade 2-> 3 Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and the [Xdebug docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/) as you edit the `.ini` file as many previous helpful posts will be outdated now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved the problem a couple of months before thanks to the optimized installation process via apt package manager and short video on YouTube from creator of XDebug Derick Rethans. Now setting up XDebug became a lot easier especially for those who just starting to learn PHP.